Transferring WhatsApp Chat DB from one device to another when both run Android higher than 9
My previous device Nokia G50 running Android 13.
My new device Galaxy A35 running Android 14.
So, according to WhatsApp's FAQ

You can only restore chats stored in your phone’s WhatsApp database if you’re using Android OS 9 or below

So, what are my other options to transfer the chats from previous device to the new one?
The previous device can no longer register to WhatsApp servers as it no longer has  SIM card in it.
I ported the (same) number from previous carrier (Mint Mobile) to a different one (Xfinity Mobile)
I can not find any Chat backup in my Google Drive although I do remember backing it up to Drive along the years. Does Drive delete it after certain time?

It's weird that the FAQ mentioned the Android 9 restriction while it's still possible in Android 11 or above.

Last sentence...possible reason
